# When a Killing vector field on Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is gradient?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold that admit a unit Killing vector field $X$. i.e., $\mathscr{L}_Xg=0$. Is it possible that there exist a smooth function $f$ on $M$ such that $X=\mathrm{grad}f$?

A good reference will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible for this to happen (for example, the unit translation vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$), but it does not necessarily hold (for example, there are unit Killing vector fields on the stanard Riemannian $3$-sphere, but, obviously, none of them could be gradients, since they never vanish and the $3$-sphere is compact).

I'm not sure what fact or theory you want a reference for.

Comment: @C.F.G:  I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.  Necessary for what?

Comment: for Killing vector field! if this vector field is not unit then your examples are correct?

Comment: @C.F.G: I really don't understand you. My examples are correct examples of what they claim: The first is a gradient vector field that is also a unit Killing field, the second is a unit Killing Field that is not a gradient vector field (even locally). In your comment/question, you didn't say what you meant by 'it', so I couldn't answer your question.  Are you asking whether a gradient Killing field is necessarily a unit vector field? (Answer: no.)  Are you asking whether a Killing field is necessarily a unit vector field? (Answer: no.)  Please ask your question in a complete self-contained way.

Answer (score 4):

The Killing condition $\nabla_a X^\flat_b + \nabla_b X^\flat_a = 0$, together with the gradient condition (really, the closedness condition for a $1$-form) $\nabla_a X^\flat_b - \nabla_b X^\flat_a = 0$, imply that $X$ is covariantly constant, $\nabla_a X^b = 0$. Note that I'm using the relation $X^\flat(-) = \langle X, - \rangle$ to define the $1$-form $X^\flat$.

The existence of covariantly constant vectors implies various restrictive conditions on the geometry of the Riemannian manifold $(M^n, g)$. If there's any particular restriction that you are interested in, you may want to refine your question.

Comment: I am not familiar with your notation, but what you call exactness rather looks like closedness. Examples asked should be even more constrained than what you implied (e.g. a flat torus has no killing field which is a gradient).

Comment: Benoît, of course you're right about the terminology  (fixed it). Sorry for the momentary vocabulary lapse! I should also make the point that my comments were meant to be considered locally, where there is no difference.

Comment: In fact no compact manifolds (w/o boundary) admit a unit vector field that is a gradient, so we can rule all of them out without even touching the Killing assumption. // The gradient condition implies that the killing field is hypersurface orthogonal, so the manifold must split as $(a,b) \times \Sigma$ with the product metric. This is an if and only if.

Comment: @C.F.G. that is elementary calculus. A smooth function on a compact manifold must attain its maximum at some point, and at that point its gradient vanishes and cannot have length one relative to any Riemannian metric. // What does Perelman's theorem have to do with this?